# 'Dots' in the url_title

Tags: url-title, codeigniter

Is there any way of forcing EE to remove 'dots' from the url title? As in an entry called "thiscompany.com" I want the url title to be thiscompanycom because other things depend on not having dots and it generally is bad practice to have it in the url (browser gets confused)

I tried this in the config file:

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%:_\-';

but the system won't override what seems to be a code ignitor default.

So my question is, where do I override this in the CI core if necessary, or some other way of doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can use any ee add-ons which can create url_titles from another field (for example - MX *Title Control) + somethink like low_replace to remove dot's.
2. You can replace it on JS level, you can use  [Foreign Character Extension](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/foreign-character-extension)
3. You can make your own ext. using [entry_submission_start](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/api/channel_entries/#entry-submission-start) hook.
4. If you decide to hack core: 
   \expressionengine\helpers\EE_url_helper.php, line 59    function url_title, after

   ```
   $trans = array(
                   '&\#\d+?;'              => '',
                   '&\S+?;'                => '',
                   '\s+'                   => $replace,
                   '[^a-z0-9\-\._]'        => '',
                   $replace.'+'            => $replace,
                   $replace.'$'            => $replace,
                   '^'.$replace            => $replace,
                   '\.+$'                  => ''
               );
   ```

just add new line

```
 $str = str_replace('.', '' , $str);
```

Comment: This doesn't help anyone logging into the admin panel and adding an entry. I know they can change this as they see it, but you would be surprised what people do, and I would rather just override it if possible from the core level.

Comment: how they can do this if url_title will be hided? I'm not sure if they decide to unhided using debug tools. If you afraid of this - make a simple ext. for entry_submission_start hook. Better then edit core.

Comment: If you decide to hack a core - I just update my answer

Comment: I just made this change in the CI core, but it still allows me to add a company.com url title to the entry?

Comment: sorry, I miss, that CI helpers is overwrite with EE - \expressionengine\helpers\EE_url_helper.php (i just tested it, so it's works)

Comment: fantastic! marked as solved